# Why am I unable to update R

Tags: r

I cannot seem to update my version of R.

Despite installing the latest R from Cran-r, when I check my version it comes back as version 3.6.1.

I have tried
`installr` and `updateR()` but unfortunately I get the following message:

> Installation status:  TRUE . Removing the file:
> C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpiSuYSt/R-4.1.1-win.exe
> (In the future, you may keep the file by setting keep_install_file=TRUE)

> We can not seem to find the location of the new R you have installed.
> The rest of the updating process is aborted, please take care to copy
> your packages to the new R installation.
> [1] TRUE

I am grateful for any help you could offer.

Many thanks

Comment: You can download an installer from CRAN: [Download R 4.1.1 for Windows](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/). Then run it like a normal Windows install program.

Comment: Hi Rui, thank you for your response. Unfortunately every time I do this, it still says my r version is 3.6.1

Comment: How are you checking your version? Are you using RStudio? You can manually change the R version within the RStudio options. If the R 4.1.1 installation works without errors then there is likely some other reason you're still seeing 3.6.1

Answer (score 2):

I was running into the same problem, and I managed to solving it by browsing to ensure that the new R version is downloaded to the same folder containing the older installation. During the error, the new R installation was creating a new R folder in a different directory. I browsed and found a n already existing R folder somewhere else (in my case, the Documents folder for some reason). Storing the new version there solved it.